# Pushing values of objects into a new array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with static values. I would like to take the startsAt and endsAt values of each object and pass it into a new array with only those 2 values.

Objects with static value:

```
var events = [{
        title: 'An event',
        type: 'warning',
        startsAt: moment().startOf('week').subtract(2, 'days').add(8, 'hours').toDate(),
        endsAt: moment().startOf('week').add(1, 'week').add(9, 'hours').toDate()
    }, {
        title: 'Another event title',
        type: 'info',
        startsAt: moment().subtract(1, 'day').toDate(),
        endsAt: moment().add(5, 'days').toDate()
    }, {
        title: 'This is a really long event title that occurs on every year',
        type: 'important',
        startsAt: moment().startOf('day').add(7, 'hours').toDate(),
        endsAt: moment().startOf('day').add(19, 'hours').toDate(),
        recursOn: 'year'
    }];
```

And I would like to take startsAt and endsAt of events and push it into checkDates:

```
var checkDates = [{
      start: this.events.startsAt,
      end: this.events.endsAt
    }];
```

How would I make it so if I console log checkDates, it will show me every start time and end time of events? The current code returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fun with map:

```
var checkDates = events.map(function (item) {
  return {
    start: item.startsAt,
    end: item.endsAt
  };
});
```

Comment: Just as a note, this won't work below IE9 as it was introduced in the ECMA-262 standard in the 5th edition. A polyfill can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill).

Answer (score 1):

With map

```
var checkDates= events.map(function (event) {
  return {
    start: event.startsAt,
    end: event.endsAt
  }
});

console.log(checkDates);
```

If browser does not support `map` then use `for`

```
var checkDates = [];

for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
  var event = events[i];
  checkDates.push({
    start: event.startsAt,
    end: event.endsAt
  });
}
```

By the way you can use `forEach`. But if browser doesn't support `forEarch`. You can use trick like this.

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.forEach != 'function') {
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(cb){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
      cb.apply(this, [this[i]]);
    }
  };
}

var checkDates = [];

events.forEach(function(event){
  checkDates.push({
    start: event.startsAt,
    end: event.endsAt
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I will keep this in mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for brevity, here is a solution without `map` (which will work on IE9 and below):

```
var checkDates = [];

for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {

  checkDates.push({ startsAt: events[i].startsAt, endsAt: events[i].endsAt });

}
```

If you'd prefer to use the JavaScript `map` method, but still want to support IE9 and below, you could always use a Polyfill [like this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill).